# laravel redirecting to original path after login(not using the laravel make:auth)

Tags: laravel

i am not using the laravel make:auth but instead i have created my own login page. 
i have this button "share your adventure" and if the the user click the button he should be redirected to the adventurefor.blade.php if he is already logged in but if he is not currently log in, he will be redirected to the login page with the use of a middleware..

here is my web.php

```
<?php
Route::get('login','userLog@login');
Route::post('loginsuccess','userLog@submit');
Route::get('share', 'userLog@shareadven')->middleware('user');
Route::post('sharesuccess','userLog@shareit')->middleware('user');
```

here is my controller

```
 public function login(){

    return view('logs.login');
}
 public function submit(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]); 


        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']]))
            {

        return Redirect::to(URL::previous())
                                -> with('info', 'Logged In Successfully!'); 

            }
        else{
            return redirect('logs.login') -> with('infos', 'Incorrect Email/Password!');
        }

 public function shareadven(){

    return view('adventure.adventureform');
}
```

here is my middleware that i created

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class User
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if( Auth::check()){

    return $next($request);

}

    return redirect('login');
}
}
```

and here is the code for my button

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{{ url('share') }}" role="button">Share your ADVENTURES</a>
```

my problem is im getting redirected to the login page after login. it should redirect to the original path that the user wants to go

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the logic of the Laravel trait [`AuthenticateUsers`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php) that redirects to the [intended](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Redirect.html#method_intended) path after the login.

This is the source from Laravel:

```
/**
  * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

And change your controller from

```
return Redirect::to(URL::previous())->with('info', 'Logged In Successfully!');
```

to

```
return Redirect::intended('your-path')->with('info', 'Logged In Successfully!');
```

Another way is to use the middleware as you where doing, but checking if the request has a "special attributes" that defines where the user should be redirected.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, but i am new to laravel and i dont know how to change the authenticatesusers to use in my own middleware. do you have other options? thank you...

Comment: You don't have to change the `AuthenticatesUsers` but just use the method `intended()` on your login controller

Comment: @Suju... My code is a suggestion not a working! `your-path` has to be changed with the route you want the user to be redirected!